# Difference in output on Azure

Tags: azure, telerik, azure-diagnostics

I've run into a little problem here. What I get on my local environment and my cloud result is different... I've tried using **IntelliTrace**, but everytime I want to debug a track it gives me a *No source available* message.

There aren't any exceptions or anything like that, everything loads perfectly fine... it just seems like the 4th case of the `switch-case` is screwed. I'm using 4 `const int`s in a static `Common.cs` file to populate these 4 possibilities; I know I could be using an `enum`, but it shouldn't really matter, right?

If this helps, I am also using Telerik's RadChart control. In other words, these 4 options manipulate the data in 4 different ways. People have told me that there is no way to debug code hosted within Azure, and that I could probably use Azure Diagnostics and keep tracing every few lines or so...

Does anyone have any pointers on which direction I should go? or have faced similar problems before? Many thanks... I am pretty much clueless in here.

**EDIT:** The problem lay with the localization on Azure. On my local machine the date format is dd/mm/yyyy, whereas on Azure it is mm/dd/yyyy. Hence, the problem arose...

Comment: You really need to show some code, maybe show some output, *something.* As it stands, this is a completely un-answerable question.

Comment: Hey there... I'm sorry, but it's all company stuff; you might have arrived at the answer quickier if I had provided more info, but... I didn't know where to start

Comment: It's an accepted practice, if you answer your own question, to then post that answer (rather than just editing your question).

Comment: Hmm, but if the other guy's idea helped me to find out the answer, I don't mark his as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're using a web role. If that's the case, the quickest way to explore differences between local deployment and azure deployment is to enable Web Deploy on your cloud project.

Once you've done that, use the Publish option on the Web project (NOT on the cloud project) to quickly upload your code changes to Azure, and explore doing old-fashioned Response.Write.

Ugly, but quite efficient when you don't get what's happening.

Pierre

Comment: Allo monsieur, chaque telecharge a Azure prends environ une minute seulement... Thank you for your idea! I quickly found out where the problem lay (as described in my EDIT)